# Publishing cython sources for linux and windows users

Tags: cython, setup.py, distutils, cythonize

I would like to publish my cython lib on pypi.

I would like to simplify a lot the life of window's users by compiling sources for 64-bits architectures as well as 32-bits architecture.

So far my setup looks like this :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

module = Extension('*', ['package/*.pyx'])

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(module))
```

When I do a `python setup.py sdist`, I can do `pip install path/to/tarball`, that compiles the sources.

My question is, if I compile with a windows vm, how can I publish the project so Unix users can compile sources themself and windows users do not compile the sources but get the `.pyd` installed in their python path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unix users create an `sdist`:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

For w32/w64 users create binary wheels:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

The wheels must be created on the same platform they will be installed; `setuptools` cannot do cross-platform compilation. So for w32/w64 you have to run 32- and 64-bit windows with the corresponding [compilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers), Python versions (binary wheels are version-dependent) and corresponding header files.

Comment: And if I publish both in the same folder to PYPi, does the `pip install` command install both correctly?

Also, would you suggest to let windows user install cython and compile it themself?

Comment: 1. Yes. For example, I [publish](https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/#files) a lot of wheels for linux and windows, 32- and 64-bit; also an sdist; gonna add MacOS wheels in the future. `pip install Cheetah3` works on any platform. 2. Very much depends on the qualification of the user; some will succeed and some fail because they need to install and configure a proper version of MSVC.

Comment: Answer accepted, thanks for the clarification and the example of your project deployment !