# How to build a Linux compatible cythonized Program on a Windows System?

Tags: linux, windows, cython, setuptools, cythonize

I have to setup a .py file with cython because the server it runs on is a has a Linux operating system. The server opens a `logic.py` which then initializes the cythonized file.

I've found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646403/publishing-cython-sources-for-linux-and-windows-users) but it doesn't really help since I don't know what to do with the build afterwards.

It creates a `dist` folder with a the `UNKOWN-0.0.0.tar.gz` file and an `UNKNOWN.egg-info` folder with some txt's in it.

When starting my `logic.py` it says that it has a circular import because it imports the module `logic` which is itself since there is no other logic from the build.

How do I access the build for Linux?